# How to test the onUpdate method on eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm coding my first app for android using Eclipse. Right now, I'm trying to test my onUpdate method but the problem is I don't know how to enter this method. I tried to change the code version number in the manifest file but it still not working.

I need help please.

Danny

ps: I want to test my app behavior after changing the database.

Comment: your question is unclear? are you talking about SqliteOpenHelper's onUpgrade method? if, then it has nothing to do with the manifest's code version.

Comment: if you want to test the database `onUpdate` method, you need change the database version, if the method in the widget, you can `ctrl+f11` to change the orientation.

Comment: there's no `onUpdate` method in database

Comment: @Waqas I want to test my app behavior after a change on the database.

Comment: @idiottiger thx I'm gonna try it.

Comment: dont get what you want...do you want to catch changes after a data insert? then you need a ContentObserver...

Comment: refer to this article http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial_database